# Jenkins - test results analyzer is not showing any result

Tags: jenkins-plugins

We are having Jenkins job for UI tests developed in C#. We tried using Test Result Analyzer plugin for the test results. But we are unable to view any results.[Test Result Analyzer report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPmSP.png) [actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35GlI.png)
Kindly, let us if we have provide any other information to view the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

- publish testing or JUnit test result in post build section
- give path to `**/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml`

[Here are some screen shots.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTd7Q.jpg)